# If, else if looping problems

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, arraylist, try-catch

so I'm just finishing up my first computer programming class ever and I'm having problems with my main method. I have 2 classes. The first class is homeClass.java and the other class is homeInventory.java. I'm just going to show you some of my homeInventory.java class unless you smarter ppl feel like it's prudent to have my other class. Basically, I'm having a problem with my else if statements. The program runs w/ the if statement, but won't completely run through the other options (else if). I must be missing something pretty apparent but I'll just see what you have to say on it. Thanks in advance!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<homeClass> homes = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        String option = "";
        String answer = "";
        String statusAnswer = "";


        do {
            System.out.println("Menu:");
            System.out.println("1. Add a new home.");
            System.out.println("2. Remove a home.");
            System.out.println("3. Update home sale status.");
            System.out.println("4. Exit");
            System.out.print("Option chosen: ");
        try {
            while(true) {
                if(scnr.hasNext()) {
                    option = scnr.next();
                break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException NSEE) {
            continue;
        }
        catch (Exception excpt) {
            excpt.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("Error, non-integer");
        break;
        }
            try {           
                    if(option.equals("1")) {
                        homes.add(addHome(scnr));
                        System.out.println("Home added.");
                        homes.get(i).getListing();
                    break;
                    }
                    else if (option.equals("2")) {
                        for(j = 0; j < homes.size(); ++j) {
                            homes.get(i).getListing();
                            System.out.print("Remove this listing? Y or N: ");
                            answer = scnr.next();
                            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                                homes.get(i).removeListing();
                                System.out.println("Home removed.");
                            }
                            else if (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                                System.out.println("Home not removed. Choose next option.");
                            }
                        }
                    break;
                    }
                    else if (option.equals("3")) {
                        for(j = 0; j < homes.size(); ++j) {
                            homes.get(i).getListing();
                            System.out.print("Do you want to change the sale status? Y or N: ");
                            answer = scnr.next();
                            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                                System.out.println("Enter home sale status: ");
                                    statusAnswer = scnr.next();
                                    homes.get(i).setSaleStatus(statusAnswer);
                                    homes.get(i).getListing();
                            }   
                        }
                    break;
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception excpt) {
                excpt.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error, option failed.");
            }
        } while(!option.equals("4"));


        System.out.print("Do you want the home information stored in a file? Y or N: ");
            answer = scnr.next();

            String outputFileName = "C:\\Temporary\\Home.txt";

            for (j = 0; j < homes.size(); ++j) {
                String listing = homes.get(i).getListing();
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                    try {
                        printToFile(listing, outputFileName);
                    } 
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("File printed to: " + outputFileName);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("File not printed.");
                }
            }

        scnr.close();
        return;

    }
}
```

Comment: *The program runs w/ the if statement, but won't completely run through the other options* - what do you mean?

Comment: where is i declared? It seems to be initialized, because for option 1 you say homes.get(i), but elsewhere it's doing duty as a for loop counter. Try making the for loop counters int j = 0, declared locally and not referring to i inside.

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile. You should be seeing a "break outside switch or loop" compilation error.

Comment: @MarsAtomic, that's it! The breaks are getting out of the while prematurely. See where it says while(!option.equals("4")). Katelyn, try commenting out the break statements.

Comment: Jeremy Kahan and @MarsAtomic, i is declared at the top of my main which I didn't include. I definitely can tho. I tried making the for loop with int j instead and the program stopped still. If I comment out the break statements, the program doesn't run through the if/else statements. I'll add the rest of the main for you to see (in my original post). Sorry i'm not explaining this well...definitely struggling over here

Comment: That's an awful way to learn programming. Please get a proper tutorial, something meaningful. If you can afford it I'd suggest getting a Pluralsight subscription. PS: Pluralsight offers a free weekend for everyone (Friday-Sunday this week). Make sure to check it out.